composite index on (A,B) + single index on (A): postgres is using single when it "should" use composite?
There are several good posts, e.g:
Should I use a composite or single-column index?
showing that if you have a composite index on columns (A,B), and a single index on (A), postgres will use the composite index (to improve caching), and the single index is superfluous and can be dropped.
When testing this, I notice that postgres will sometimes use the single index when the composite is available, but I don't know if this means we still need (for query performance) both indexes.
Consider the following:
CREATE TABLE public.events (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    reference int4 NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(255) NULL,
    bet_source varchar NULL,
    CONSTRAINT events_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT events_reference_betsource_key UNIQUE (reference, bet_source)
);
CREATE INDEX event_reference ON public.events USING btree (reference);

Here the slight difference is he composite index is unique, and was declared as a constraint (which I assume is the same as creating a unique index)
explain (analyze, buffers)
select * from events e where e.reference = 123;

Index Scan using event_reference on events e  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (reference = 123)
  Buffers: shared hit=2
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=69 dirtied=1
Planning Time: 0.432 ms
Execution Time: 0.036 ms

Here we can see from the explain plan that postgres has chosen to use the single index.  Usually when I tested this on other tables, postgres choses the composite index in this case.
The question is,

am I safe to remove the event_reference without affecting query performance?  As I dont have access to production data (or a copy of it), testing this with real data would be difficult.

is a unique constraint the same as a unique index (for the purposes of query and insert optimization)



The single-column index is superfluous and can be dropped.
PostgreSQL will still use the single-column index, since it is smaller and shallower and faster to scan. So you will lose a tiny bit of query performance by dropping the single-column index, but that will almost always be outbalanced by the performance improvement for data modifications.
As far as query performance is concerned, a unique constraint and a unique index are the same. The main difference is that a foreign key constraint can reference a unique constraint, but not a unique index.
